# Is there a way to paste documented R code into R console or Rstudio without the arrow or plus signs being registered?

Tags: r

This will make more sense with an example. Typical R manuals from CRAN show R code with a line starting with > and indentations indicated with +. See 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/vignettes/gettingstartedMC.pdf
for an example.

The trouble is that you can't cut and paste that into a console without copying it into an editor and removing those arrow and plus characters. Is there an easier way to execute that text as R code? I figured that somebody must have dealt with this problem. Otherwise, I guess I'll write a script.

Comment: In RGui, there's an option to 'Paste commands only'.

Comment: That would be Windows RGUI.

Comment: Welll I don't know how to do it in R-Studio, but 'paste commands only' works in R. At least it does in Windows. It would be handy if R Studio had a way to do it. I imagine it does and I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: @Glen_b: Again, that is a behavior of the Windows R GUI, and it is not present in the vanilla R console in any OS implementation. I wouldn't be surprised to see it added to RStudie in the future, but as far as I can see it isn't there yet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The writing has already been done.

[2009 post by Duncan Murdoch:](http://markmail.org/search/?q=list:org.r-project.r-help%20paste%20mac%20%22%2b%22#query:list:org.r-project.r-help%20paste%20mac%20%22%2b%22%20page:1%20mid:rilimp3xoxk56mnt%20state:results)

```
CleanTranscript <- function(lines) {
         lines <- grep("^[[:blank:]]*[^>+[:blank:]]*[>+]", lines, value = TRUE) 
         lines <- sub("^[[:blank:]]*[^>+[:blank:]]*[>+] ?", "", lines) }

source(textConnection(CleanTranscript(
       # This is the Windows input strategy
       readLines("clipboard")
       # See below for Mac version
                      )), 
                      echo = TRUE, max.deparse.length=Inf)
```

[Subsequent 2009 R-help post by Gabor Grothendieck:](http://markmail.org/message/oblxhml236jgwxmm?q=list:org.r-project.r-help%20paste%20mac%20%22%2b%22)

```
process.source <- function(action = c("both", "run", "show"), echo = TRUE,
    max.deparse.length = Inf, ...) { 
    # This is the Mac input strategy
    L <- readLines(pipe("pbpaste"))
    #  for Windows devices use
    #  L <- readLines("clipboard")
    rx <- "^[[:blank:]]*[^>+[:blank:]]*[>+]" 
    is.cmd <- grepl(rx, L) 
    L[is.cmd] <- gsub(paste(rx, "?"), "", L[is.cmd]) 
    L[!is.cmd] <- paste("#", L[!is.cmd]) 
    action <- match.arg(action) 
  if (action != "run") for(el in L) cat(el, "\n") 
  if (action == "both") cat("##################################\n") 
  if (action != "show") 
       source(textConnection(L), echo = echo, 
       max.deparse.length = max.deparse.length, ...) 
invisible(L) }
```

Note: The upvotes prompted me to post this as a "feature request" on the RStudio Discussion Board. Although I have not broken it yet, it might need more testing if it were to be built in to the RStudio framework.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a nice `RStudio` `Addin` called `mischelper` (https://github.com/dracodoc/mischelper) where one of its functions does this exactly. The benefit of having it as an `Addin` is that you can turn it into a keyboard shortcut. Usually paste is `Ctrl + V` so I have script/code I wanted copied in from the console as `Ctrl + B`. It pastes code such as:

```
> x <- 3
> switch(x, 2+2, mean(1:10), rnorm(5))
[1]  2.2903605  2.3271663 -0.7060073  1.3622045 -0.2892720


> centre <- function(x, type) {
+ switch(type,
+        mean = mean(x),
+        median = median(x),
+        trimmed = mean(x, trim = .1))
+ }
> x <- rcauchy(10)
> centre(x, "mean")
[1] 0.8760325
```

into:

```
x <- 3
switch(x, 2+2, mean(1:10), rnorm(5))
# [1]  2.2903605  2.3271663 -0.7060073  1.3622045 -0.2892720


centre <- function(x, type) {
  switch(type,
         mean = mean(x),
         median = median(x),
         trimmed = mean(x, trim = .1))
  }
x <- rcauchy(10)
centre(x, "mean")
# [1] 0.8760325
```